# how to add custom app in rally from github?

Tags: rally

How to add this github project into my rally workspace https://github.com/RallyCommunity/PortfolioItem-Tree. I am looking for project tracking (Features \ release tracking app in rally. Can please share if you come across any

Answer (score 0):

For detailed instructions, try this help page: https://docs.ca.com/en-us/ca-agile-central/saas/use_apps